# Specific styling pattern for nested and non-nested links in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website, and I want a rather specific pattern for the styling of my links, but I don't know how to do it.

What I basically want is the following result:

- a red link
- a green link
- a red link
- a green link
- …

**Here's my html**

```
<div id="aRandomDivforThisQuestion">
        <a href="#">a red link</a>
        <p>
            <a href="#">a green link</a>
            <a href="#">a red link again</a>
        </p>
        <a href="#">yet again a green link</a>
</div><!-- /aRandomDivForThisQuestion -->
```

**… and this is the CSS I tried, which I knew would not get the job done to begin with**

```
#aRandomDivforThisQuestion a:nth-of-type(odd) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}

#aRandomDivforThisQuestion a:nth-of-type(even) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3DCD7C;
    color: #3DCD7C;
}
```

So, in a nutshell : what I want is that every  tag within the  tag with id  aRandomDivForThisQuestion follows this pattern regardless of the fact wether it's a child of the div, or the child of a child of the div, …

Can you guys help me out here?

PS: css solution, javascript solution, jquery solution, … doesn't really matter.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just CSS.

Comment: `nth-of-type` is acting like `nth-child` except that `nth-of-type` used to children with same type. **eg.** div, span, li, a class name ... --   each level of children is independant from others (ie: child of child).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first things first, wrapping things in a p element to inherit display properties is not really good practice. Even though you are working on a front-end design, your code should still be structured according to your data/elements. If you try to write your code according to the design, it will just make things harder for you, moreover will be hard to read/update in the future. In this specific case, relying on a P element's attributes will cause side effects and you might actually end up spending time, trying to figure out what is wrong.

1) If you need to group elements, use divs.

2) Group only if it makes sense. If it will help you coding wise.(the children of the group will have common properties etc.)

Coming back to you question. Try using

```
:nth-child()
```

Once you get rid of the

element.

```
:nth-child(odd)

:nth-child(even)
```

Will do all the work for you by switching between green and red

https://jsfiddle.net/dLh25u0r/1/

Jquery solution for nesting a elements:
In this solution I use:

```
 .each()
```

Which will iterate through every instance of a inside the div that you want, regardless of they are nested or not. Make sure you place the code inside this for it to run.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          //add the code
    })
 </script>
```

And import Jquery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8swLcdcz/

Comment: It isn't? I always thought it was … I've seen it in many sites, really.

Comment: They do it because it is easy solution to certain problems but in your case, as your website gets more complicated, it might cause positioning problems that will drive you crazy. Anyway please check the second link in the solution. It will help you nest a elements in anyway you want but it uses Jquery

Comment: Thanks for the help mate! You really helped me out here. I had tried :nth-child(), but I knew this wouldn't work for nested links, so I wanted to try something in CSS for nested links, but I guess these are problems CSS alone can't solve …

Comment: No worries! Make sure you click the tick mark to let future visitors of this question know that this answer works

Comment: One final question: where do I need to place the JQuery? When I put it between the <head> tag it doesn't work and when I place it under or above the aRandomDivForThisQuestion div it doesn't work either (and yes it's between <script> tags).

Comment: @RainbowDasher I agree with sinanspd - try to write your markup in a way that represents the _structure_ of your page, **not** the appearance, that is, avoid wrapping things in p's or div's just for appearance sake; wrap them if they make a logical grouping. -- sinanspd — I would upvote your answer if you explained more here rather than relying on just the fiddle link.

Comment: @RainbowDasher Jquery should be placed like this 
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        //The code in the fiddle goes here
})
</script>
Also make sure you are importing Jquery 

2
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @StephenP yeah you are right, needs more explanation. I still appreciate you agreeing tho haha. I am adding some explanation anyway just for the sake of future visitors

Comment: @RainbowDasher let me know if you can not get it to work

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with CSS is going to be prohibitively verbose (actually, impossible when I start to think about it).  It's the `<p>` tags that *F* this up because `:nth-child` only affects direct children... not grandchildren and other descendants.  Your only solution is to use javascript or put the links in a flat list and use class names to get the paragraph styling you want:

```
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="p-start">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="p-end">link 4</a>
<a href="#">link 5</a>
```

And this CSS:

```
a { display: block }
a:nth-child(odd) { color: red }
a:nth-child(even) { color: green }
a.p-start { margin-top: 1em; }
a.p-end { margin-bottom: 1em; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r0b87pp4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using `nth-child` won't work because your links aren't all children of the same element, and using `nth-of-type` won't work because each new generation (child, grandchild of a node) gets it's own *"-of-type"* ... that is ***n*** is reset.

You can use javascript or jQuery to attach arbitrary classes to each link within a container — a subtree of any given DOM element — including every link in the body.

Given some set of `<a>` nodes and some set of classes to loop through and attach, it doesn't matter what depth the nodes are at as long as you have some way to select them.

In jQuery, `$('#aRandomDivforThisQuestion a')` will select all the links within your div and not any other links.  You could use `$('body a')` or just `$(a)` to get *all* links on the page, or `$('.linkmap a')` to get all links within a class but no others.

It's then a matter of traversing the list of nodes and assigning a class to each one, re-starting your classes every other, or every third, etc. node, depending on how many variations you want.  You could do just `['odd', 'even']` (every other link) or `['red', 'blue', 'green']` (every third link)

Here's a function to take an arbitrary list of links and apply an arbitrary set of classes to it.  It's more verbose than necessary (lines could be combined) but is clearer this way.
It expects a jQuery list of elements and a plain javascript array of class names.

```
function stripe(elems, classes)
{
    var which = 0;
    $(elems).each(function(i, elem) {
        var addit = classes[which];
        which = (which + 1) % classes.length;
        $(elem).addClass(addit);
    });
}
```

See it in action in my [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/py24091q/) where I apply two different sets of classes to the same set of nodes, setting every other link to red/green and every third link to bold/italic/underline, by calling the function twice.

```
stripe( $('#aRandomDivforThisQuestion a'),
        [ 'odd', 'even' ] );

stripe( $('#aRandomDivforThisQuestion a'),
        [ 'bld', 'ital', 'undrln' ] );
```

Answer (score -3):

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question.